# Pure Java MPEG DASH library

Tags: java, video, streaming, mpeg-dash, mpeg

Is there any PURE Java open source project to deal with MPEG4 or MPEG-DASH (aka MPEG Dash) without using native C or C++ libraries out there?

Comment: For creating DASH streams from plain MP4 files you might use dash.encrypt https://github.com/castlabs/dashencrypt